# iOS: What's a safe way to create a temporary directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, temporary

I read that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returns a string for a temporary directory, but may also return nil.
Is this the case in iOS? Has anyone experience with `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returning nil? When does it happen?

If i have to be prepared that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` may return nil, it does not make sense for me to use it altogether. If i have to provide a fallback mechanism i can use this mechanism in the first place.

So what is a simple and safe way to create a temporary directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Being realistic, any situation that would lead NSTemporaryDirectory to return nil, would most likely mean that you wouldn't be able to save anything yourself anyway.

i.e.: It's likely to mean that the device is full, or that some form of corruption has occurred.

As such, I suspect that you should stick to using NSTemporaryDirectory (why re-invent the wheel after all) and treat it returning nil as effectively meaning you can't write to local storage.

Comment: the documentation for that method states _"See the NSFileManager method `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` for an alternate (and more flexible) means of finding the correct temporary directory."_